# rock paper scissors Java method

Tags: java, expression

I've been trying out a Rock-Paper-Scissors Java code.

Although, I'm blocked and I can't figure out why I have so many error within my method, and why each of my `int k` is wrong.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class chifoumi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Bienvenu à CHIFOUMI...");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Pierre, feuille, ciseaux?");
        System.out.println("Tape 0, 1 où 2"); // 0 : Pierre
        int joueur = sc.nextInt(); // 1 : Feuille
                                    // 2 : Ciseaux

        int V = jeu(joueur);
        if (V == 1)
            System.out.println("Vous avez gagné !");
        else if (V == 0)
            System.out.println("Vous avez perdu... ");
        else if (V == 2)
            System.out.println("Egalité ! Recommencez ;)");

    }

    public static int jeu(int x){
            Random random = new Random();
            int ordi;
            ordi = random.nextInt(3); 
            if (x == 0 || ordi == 1)
                int k = 0; 
                return k; 
            if (x == 0 || ordi == 2)
                int k = 1; 
                return k; 
            if (x == 1 || ordi == 0)
                int k = 1; 
                return k; 
            if (x == 1 || ordi == 2)
                int k = 0; 
                return k; 
            if (x == 2 || ordi == 0)
                int k = 0; 
                return k; 
            if (x == 2 || ordi == 1)
                int k = 1;
                return k; 
            if (ordi == x)
                int k =2;
                return k;
     }
}
```

Apparently, within my method, all of my `int k = ...` are wrong... can't figure out why.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 2):

Your methods of the form

```
if (x == 0 || ordi == 1)
    int k = 0; 
    return k;
```

are all *actually*

```
if (x == 0 || ordi == 1)
    int k = 0; 
return k;
```

since java is not indentation-based. You therefore always return after the first statement. That means the statements after it are unreachable which is why the compiler complains. What you should write is

```
if (x == 0 || ordi == 1) {
    int k = 0; 
    return k; 
}
```

Or even simpler drop the `k` and write

```
if (x == 0 || ordi == 1) {
    return 0; 
}
```

in which case you can actually omit the curly braces again since you only have one statement executing conditionally on the `if`:

```
if (x == 0 || ordi == 1)
    return 0;
```

Note that in the end of the `jeu` method you need an additional `return something;` or `throw something` since the compiler cannot ensure all the `if`s are exhaustive and you would always hit on of the `if`s.

---

You should use an IDE that does some auto-formatting / -indenting for you which makes these *basic* kinds of errors easier to spot.

Comment: thank you so much, you really debugged me there !!
I'll be sure to check my indentation now :)

Comment: @hugoch you are welcome, please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on its top left if it solved your problem.